# Convergence of $\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i \cdot f(i)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

[Edited to fix typo]

Is there a precise formulation for when the sum

$$
\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i \cdot f(i)}
$$ converges, in terms of the function $f$?  Assume that $f$ is smooth and monotonically increasing.

If $f(i) \gtrsim i^c$ for any $c>0$ then we know it converges. If $f(i)$ is a constant then we know it doesn't.  We can try functions in between.  For example setting $f(i) = 2^{\sqrt{\log(i)}}$ makes the sum converge but setting $f(i) = \log(i)$ makes it diverge according to Wolfram Alpha

There are of course a lot of functions so it might be hard to write a full classification. How about if we only including elementary functions that, for example, use only powers and logs?

**Update.**  Is something like the following conjecture true? Consider $\sum_{i=\ell}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i \cdot f(i)}$ and set $\ell$ to be the smallest positive integer so that $f(\ell) >0$.  The sum converges if and only if there exists $c>0$ such that $f(i) \gtrsim c \log(i)\log{\log(i)}\log{\log{\log(i)}}\dots$  where the $\log$ is applied an (as yet) unknown but fixed number of times.

Comment: Am I missing something, or the series is just $\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac1{f(i)}$?

Comment: @Majid Generally not good to use $f'$ for "some other function," since it carries the derivative connotation a lot of the time.

Comment: Aargh! That's just a typo!

Comment: What's the right term?

Comment: With $f(i)=\log(i)$, this series does not converge. The integral test can be used to prove that.

Comment: alex.jordan Thanks . I got there at roughly the same time it seems.

Comment: if you carried out the log process indefinitely, it would appear that you're saying $f(i) \displaystyle >_{~}$ imaginary number? What is the range set of $f(x)$? Is it $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: RustynYazdanpour It is $\mathbb{R}$. Do you have a better conjecture? Note that $f(i) = \log{i}\log{\log(i)}$ diverges but $f(i) = \log{i}(\log{\log(i)})^2$ converges.

Comment: @Majid No matter what, if you repeatedly apply $\log$ to a fixed natural number (indefinitely), eventually you will get an imaginary number. What do you think about this?

Comment: RustynYazdanpour See comment below (and edit above).

Comment: @Majid Sorry I just got your comment on my answer. Is there some fixed $k$? Not sure, would depend on the function.

Comment: RustynYazdanpour Which function? We are trying to define a function that is exactly at the border of convergence and divergence currently.

Comment: @Majid I see. Let me twiddle my thumbs.

Comment: @Majid, my guess would be that you would have to come up with a function such that the sum _barely_ converges. You could do this by making $f(x)$ ~ $x^{1 + \epsilon}$ for $\epsilon > 0$

Comment: Let us call $\dfrac1{f(n)}$ as $b(n)$.

First note that from Abel summation, we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N a(n) b(n) = \sum_{n=1}^N b(n)(A(n)-A(n-1)) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} b(n) A(n) - \sum_{n=1}^N b(n)A(n-1)\\
= \sum_{n=1}^{N} b(n) A(n) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}^N b(n+1)A(n) = b(N) A(N) - b(1)A(0) + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A(n) (b(n)-b(n+1))$$
where $A(n) = \displaystyle \sum_{k \leq n} a(k)$.

In our case, $a(n) = \dfrac1n$. Hence, $A(n) = \log(n) + \gamma + \mathcal{O}(1/n)$.
Hence, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{b(k)}k$$ converges if and only if $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \log(n)(b(n)-b(n+1))$$ converges.

Comment: @Marvis Thanks, yet again, for this piece of enlightenment.

Comment: @Marvis That's very interesting indeed.  I hope you can turn this into an answer too.

Comment: @Marvis could you explain your indices for your very last line? $b(n)$ is denoted as $\frac{1}{f(n)}$ but our index variable is $k$, I understand why $\log(n)$ has $n$. Just a little confused.

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour It is a typo. The summation index for the sum in the last line is $n$ and not $k$.

Comment: @Marvis Whoops, nevermind...

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour Just to clarify what I meant was
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{b(k)}k$$ converges iff
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \log(k) (b(k) - b(k+1))$$ converges.

Comment: @Majid I am not sure if what I left as a comment is useful as such and hence I am not turning it into an answer.

Comment: @Majid I'm sorry for all the strikethroughs but those are due in part to your editing of the question and my misinterpretation of your question because of the typos. If all of it is useless, I can delete the answer. I decided to strikethrough everything that is no longer relevant. ~Russ

Comment: There will not be a fastest growing function that causes divergence if we allow ourselves to use arbitrary smooth, monotone functions. 

Suppose that $f$ is such that the sum converges. Set $S_n =\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i \cdot f(i)}$. $S_n$ is a monotonically increasing sequence that goes to infinity. 

Set $g(i) = f(i) \cdot S_i$. (There are infinitely many smooth, monotone functions that satsify this.) Then $\sum_i \frac{1}{i \cdot g(i)}$ also diverges, even though the ratio $f(i)/g(i)$ goes to zero. A proof can be found in Konrad Knopp's book on infinite series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is monotonically increasing, we can use the integral test.

Define repeated composition by
$$
f^{\circ0}(x)=x\quad\text{and}\quad f^{\circ k+1}(x)=f\circ f^{\circ k}(x)
$$

Note that if
$$
f_n(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n\log^{\circ k}(x)
$$
then, for $n>0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\exp^{\circ n}(1)}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{xf_n(x)\log^{\circ n}(x)^a}
&\stackrel{\hphantom{\text{induction}}}=\int_{\exp^{\circ n}(1)}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}\log(x)}{f_n(x)\log^{\circ n}(x)^a}\\
&\stackrel{\substack{x\mapsto e^x\\\hphantom{\text{induction}}}}=\int_{\exp^{\circ n-1}(1)}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{xf_{n-1}(x)\log^{\circ n-1}(x)^a}\\
&\stackrel{\text{induction}}=\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{a+1}}\\
&\stackrel{\hphantom{\text{induction}}}=\frac1a
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, for all $n\ge0$,
$$
\int_{\exp^{\circ n}(1)}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{xf_n(x)}
$$
diverges, yet for any $a>0$,
$$
\int_{\exp^{\circ n}(1)}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{xf_n(x)\log^{\circ n}(x)^a}
$$
converges. As far as logs and powers go, these border convergence/divergence pretty closely.

Comment: Intriguing.  The sum seems such a standard question I feel sure someone must have considered it before.

Answer (score 1):

Extrapolating off of Marvis's work in the comments section, we see that if $b(n)$ is similar to $\dfrac{1}{\log(n)^{k}}$ for a fixed $k\ge 2$, ($k$ exponent here) then the series will converge. Furthermore, if $b(n)$ is similar to $\dfrac{1}{\log(n)}$ we observe divergence. Consider extending this process to a fixed $j$ so that if $b(n)$ is similar to $\dfrac{1}{\log n\log\log n \log\log\log n ...\log^{(j)} n}$, we have divergence. These are mere examples. 
In general, 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \log(n)(b(n) - b(n+1)) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \log(n)b(n) - \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \log(n)b(n+1) 
\end{align*}
If $b(n)$ is a non-decreasing function then 
\begin{align*}
b(n) \le b(n+1) \Rightarrow \\
\mbox{ For $n\ge2$ we have } \log(n)b(n) \le \log(n)b(n+1) \Rightarrow \\
\log(n)b(n)-\log(n)b(n+1) \le 0 \\ 
\end{align*}
Now $b'(n) \ge 0$. 
If $b'(n) = 0$, then the entire sum is $0$. (Uninteresting) 
If $b'(n) > 0$ (Increasing) and $b''(n)>0$ (Second Derivative also increasing), then for $n >>2$ 
$\log(n)b(n)-\log(n)b(n+1)$ ~ $-\log(n)b(n+1)$ 
$b(n) -b(n+1)$ can get arbitrarily large because the vertical distance between $b(n)$ and $b(n+1)$ approaches $\infty$. This is because for any interval, $[n,n+1]$, we have this by the MVT. 
So it would stand within reason that the sum would tend to $-\infty$. 
What about when $b''(n) < 0 $  but $b'(n) > 0 $ $\forall n$ ? 
Well the derivative is decreasing implying that for any interval $[n,n+1]$, the vertical distance between $b(n)$ and $b(n+1)$ is decreasing by MVT, so the sum would eventually converge.

Comment: You'd better use $n$ instead of $i$. ;-)

Comment: @BabakSorouh I'm not sure where? And pardon my asking but are you Iranian?

Comment: RustynYazdanpour You are right that it can't go on forever.  So it is true for some fixed $k$?

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour: Although, we are working on series and there is not difficulty to use $i$ rather than $n$; it would be better use $n$. That is it. Like your answer. +1 Any way yes, I am. ;-)

Comment: @BabakSorouh Me too. I have a relative  named Babak.

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour: Nice ;-)